# Accessing an item within a document returns nothing, but does return the document

Tags: reactjs, meteor

I have a `tracker` in `componentDidMount` and I am trying to access items inside of my collection called `notes`.  However, when I `console.log(doc)` it returns the document I want to find, but when I `console.log(doc.likes)` it does not return anything and gives an error of `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'likes' of undefined`.  What I am trying to do is when the page loads, sets the state of `likes: doc.likes.length`.  Right now it works, but you have to add add a like to the array in order for it to fetch all of the likes.

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      doc: {},
      likes: 0,
      dislikes: 0
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    Meteor.subscribe("notes");
    this.tracker = Tracker.autorun(() => {
      let doc = Notes.findOne(this.props.match.params.noteId);
      console.log(doc.likes)
      this.setState({ doc })
    })
  }
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if(this.props.match.params.noteId != nextProps.match.params.noteId)
      this.tracker = Tracker.autorun(() => {
        const doc = Notes.findOne(nextProps.match.params.noteId);
        console.log(doc.likes)
        this.setState({ doc });
      })
  }
  renderNote(doc){
    return(
      <div className="fullSize-container">
        <div className="left">
          <img className="fullSize-image" src={doc.imageURL} />
          <p className="center">
            <span onClick={() => {
              Meteor.call("like", doc._id, doc.userEmail, (err, res) => {
                this.setState({ likes: res })
              })
            }}>⬆</span>
            {this.state.likes}
            <span onClick={() => {
              Meteor.call("dislike", doc._id, doc.userEmail, (err, res) => {
                this.setState({ dislikes: res })
              })
            }}>⬇</span>
            {this.state.dislikes}
          </p>
        </div>
        <div className="right">
          <h2>{doc.title}</h2>
          <h3>{doc.userEmail}</h3>
          <br />
          <span className="description">{doc.description}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div className="center">
        <Menu />
        {this.renderNote(this.state.doc)}
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is not with the `likes` property, but with the situation that your `doc` is `undefined`. The error text is clearly states that:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'likes' of undefined

That would be because you're using `Tracker.autorun` too soon after `Meteor.subscribe` and your `notes` collection didn't get its documents *before* you're using `const doc = Notes.findOne(...)`.

There are two ways to solve that:

**[not recommended]** Call `Tracker.autorun` in subscription's `onReady` callback to ensure that subscription is ready (collection's documents have been received):

```
Meteor.subscribe('notes', () => {
  this.tracker = Tracker.autorun(...);
  ...
});
```

**[recommended]** Check for `doc` value before using it:

```
const doc = Notes.findOne(...);
if (doc == null) {
  return;
}
...
```

Comment: Why is the first solution not recommended?

Comment: Because collection's `ready` state does not guarantee that there _will_ be any documents :)

Comment: @StuartFong The best way would be to merge both solutions, of course :)

Comment: A very common pattern is `doc && doc.key` in cases where `doc` may arrive asynchronously. Javascript's logic circuiting will avoid throwing an error on the second part of that expression when `doc` is `undefined`.